# Why assign a variable to another variable?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I don't understand why this is done:

```
public class Example {
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    Example(String firstName, String secondName) {
        name = firstName;
        surname = secondName;
    }
    // whatever other code goes here
}
```

I don't see why I'd need to set `name = firstName` and `surname = secondName`. Why can't I just set `name` and `surname` directly?

Comment: You are setting them directly.

Comment: Well, that constructor won't compile at the very least.

Comment: @Compass Why not? This class compiles fine.

Comment: @bcsb1001 _Before the edit was made_, it read `Example(firstName, secondName)`.

Answer (score 5):

These are not the same kinds of variables:

- `firstName` and `secondName` are method parameters. As soon as the method is over, these variables go out of scope
- `name` and `surname`, on the other hand, are fields in a class. They remain "attached" to the instance of that class for as long as the instance exists.

Here is an illustration of what that means:

```
String a = "Hello";
String b = "World";
// For the duration of the constructor, a becomes firstName,
// and b becomes secondName
Example e = new Example(a, b);
// Once the constructor exists, firstName and secondName disappear.
// Resetting a and b after the call is no longer relevant
a = "Quick brown fox jumps";
b = "over the lazy dog";
System.out.println(e.getName()+" "+e.getSurname());
```

The valuesof `a` and `b` have changed, but the values stored in `Example` remain set to what you passed to the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

#### You should best write it like this (good practice):

```
Example(String firstName, String secondName) {
    this.name = firstName;
    this.surname = secondName;
}
```

This refers to this object. firstname and secondname are both parameters you will pass in later. So you are assigning two values to the fields of your Example object

Comment: It's not necessary to include `this` in his example, seeing as there are no conflicting variable names.

Comment: Not necessary but suggested for clarity, at least that's what I did when I was learning OO

Answer (score 0):

When you call the method you will pass the names as arguments to your parameters name and surname.

```
Example test = new Example("Derrick", "Hamilton");
```

The names then will be stored in the object created from the class.  The parameters name and surname are just temporary holders for the data.  After the constructor is complete these variables will cease to exist.

Comment: The names are passed as *arguments* - `firstName` and `secondName` are the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, firstName and secondName (as function parameters) only have method level scope, therefore as soon as control returns from this method, the data will be lost.  On the other hand, name and surname will be stored and available for other calls into the object created by this constructor.

Answer (score 0):

name and surname are the instance(member) variable defined in a class called Example. When you create the object of Example class, memory get allocated to these two variable and initialized by default value. Scope of these variable remain till the object exists. You can access these variable  with the reference of object.

firstName and secondName are the local variable(method parameter), once you come out the method,scope of these variable not exists. You can't access these variable outside the method.

in the Example method this is not the general method its a Example class contructor. When you create the Example object by passing the value for fistName and secondName it will call the parameter constructor and set the value from firstname to name and secondName to surname.

For best practice always define default constructor with parameter constructor.

```
Example()
{
}
```